# Firebase Security Rules -> prevent delete, write as unauthorized

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set Firebase security rules as:

- No one can read the data
- Anyone can write data, new record is under
  unique identifier
- No one can overwrite current data
- No one can delete data

The structure of the database is:

```
<db_name>
  users
    -L09I7kaAYExzzxB3N82 // this is unique ID generated by push()
    ....
```

My current rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

How to set it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "newData.exists() && !data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd recommend reading the Firebase documentation, specifically the section on [new data vs existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).